# Get Window Handle of Window Under Cursor

Tags: c++, windows

I'm wondering if getting the window handle of a window underneath the cursor's current position is possible in c++.  I'm working on a screenshot program that can take partial screenshots and I think that a feature where you are able to take a screenshot of a window by pressing a hotkey when your cursor is over that window would be useful feature.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function you're looking for is **[`WindowFromPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**.

Answer (score 18):

The following works:

```
   POINT P;
   HWND Handle;

   GetCursorPos(&P);

   Handle=WindowFromPoint(P);
```